# Can anyone help to figure out how to upload a file to window azure server using objective c

Tags: objective-c, https, nsurlconnection, nsurl

I want to upload a file to window azure storage using accountkey and account name. Can anyone help me to achieve this in objective c.

i tried the code

NSString *urlString = :@"https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/coretest";

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"0xLhTaLbOkNdArZ"];

//Reading the file
NSString *filePath = @"/Users/rcj/Documents/Xcode.rtf";
NSLog(@"file Path to upload: %@",filePath);
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"Xcode.rtf\"\r\n"]      dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:myData];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSString *dateString = [self rfc1123String:now];
NSString *AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME = @"myaccount";
NSString *password = @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==";

[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SharedKey %@:%@",AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME, password] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

[request addValue:dateString forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-ms-date"];

[request addValue:@"application/atom+xml, application/xml"forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

[request addValue:@"UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Charset"];

[request setHTTPBody:body]; 

NSLog(@"Headers: %@", [request allHTTPHeaderFields]);

NSLog(@"URL: %@", [[request URL] absoluteString]);
connection =[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if(connection) {
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}

else {
       // Inform the user that the con
 }
```

Thanks RCJ

Comment: You've put NSURLConnection as one of the tags, why don't you start researching them and how to use HTTP POST method inside of them, then report back with something you have /tried/. This isn't a place where you should expect to be led through everything, in fact if you do that, you're denying yourself from actually enjoying programming, there's nothing better than solving problem after problem. Sure you may need a little pointer here or there; in that case, that is when you post here, with code for things that you have tried.

Comment: Aside from that, the first thing I searched happened to be a tutorial (though outdated) that is incredibly relevant: http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/05/windows-azure-toolkit-for-ios/

Comment: Hi James, i was trying the above mentioned code. I don't want to use any libraries for connection.

Comment: You need to implement the relevant delegate methods for NSURLConnection

Comment: I added all the delegate including authentication challenge method which are mentioned on https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE. still i am not able to upload a file.  I tried the above code to upload a file to http server it working fine but not in case of window azure

Comment: NSLog the response from the server and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon this https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-mobile-services#readme where you can download the [iOS SDK for Azure beta](https://go.microsoft.com/fwLink/?LinkID=266533&clcid=0x409)

Comment: Did it work? Then you could add some details on how you did it and eventually mark the question as answered.